# Disable layout for page under Blazor

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

In Razor syntax, to disable the layout for a specific page we can do this:

```
  @{
    Layout = null
  }
```

In Blazor, the convention for it is defined by `@layout`. However, I cannot see how we can set it as null / disable. I wish to apply it to only the `index.razor` page.

How can this be achieved in Blazor?

Comment: This link may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/layouts?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @MichaelWashington Thanks for the comment. I am aware of that link, and I did review before posting. I do not see anything that helps my scenario.

Comment: Perhaps set the default layout page to be 'empty' then define a layout for index.razor called "IndexLayout" and then put this at the top of the Index.razor page: @layout IndexLayout

Comment: @MichaelWashington It is not the ideal solution but it works. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In my `Blazor-server-side` project, i resolved this issue with following two steps.

**Step 1:** First create a new empty `razor component` named `EmptyLayout`.

> EmptyLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main">    
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step 2,** To set `Layout=null`, I use the below code in the top of all required pages

```
@layout EmptyLayout
```

Comment: Thanks @Osman - Michael posted the same. In the end, I went for the solution you guys suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a direct replacement because the Blazor page is still wrapped in whatever layout is in _Hosts.cshtml.

Comment: This solution causes a split second "flicker" of the original `MainLayout` before the override kicks in for me.

Comment: I did this but even if I remove all the HTML it still puts a space at the top of the page. There must be a better solution?! Can you just tell it not to use any layout now it's 2.5 years later?

Comment: @niico Unfortunately this feature is still in their backlog. You can keep up with it here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27169

Comment: This https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8340 was retagged  so there is some new discussion....

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was to add Controllers to the Blazor project and let those controllers return any bare content without layout.

So remove the Blazor component that has the @page "/yourpage" directive, and add a controller with a [Route("/yourpage")] instead that returns what you want.