# Blazor disable _Hosts File for some pages

Tags: asp.net-core, layout, blazor, blazor-server-side, hosts

I created my first Blazor Server Application. I designed html sites to print invoices, reports etc.
The problem is, if I print this pages, all theme and layouts are visible, that from Hosts file come.

To set the @layout=null or create EmptyLayout as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518988/disable-layout-for-page-under-blazor) don't solve my proplem, because it also don't disable _Hosts file

Is it possible to create a different Hosts file or disable it only for certain pages?

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60972771/blazor-multiple-host-cshtml) may help you fix your issue. You could try not to render what you want based on a condition.

Comment: What part of _Host is giving you problems? It contains almost no mark-up. Maybe look into creating a Printlayout instead. You can use media queries for `print`.

Comment: Create a blank Blazor layout page and set that as the layout page for your print Blazor pages. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thank you guys. I read the comments already before I wrote this post. If I create new pages in Blazor, this inherits html from _Hosts file like css, scripts... This aproach is good for regular usage. But for some receipt reports I want to create whole html in one component. If this page is requested, it should not inherit from _Hosts. For example my Print.razor component: 
    @page "/print"
    <h1>Welcome</h1>

and when domain.com/print is requested, the source code should only include:

<h1>Welcome</h1>

NOTHING MORE.
We achieved this via GenericHandler(.ashx) in Asp.Net Webforms

Comment: If `GenericHandler(.ashx)` resolved your issue, you could post that as answer.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron
GenericHandler would solve my issue, can I implement it in Blazor?

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but why not use CSS and `@media print` to override the styles you don't want used when printing the page?

Comment: In _Hosts.cshtml there are bunch of css styles, javascript links, theme settings, background images etc. To put @media print for all this is a mess. It should be a way to bypass _Hosts file for some pages. Unfortunately I couldn't find it :(