# How to redirect to login if unauthorized - page loads inside @Body

Tags: blazor, authorization, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I am facing 2 issues when trying to redirect a user to the login page if he is not authenticated.

The first one is that when I am trying to use a redirect component directly in the MainLayout.razor, it gets pulled in a loop where it tries to redirect to the login page again and again. Render-mode is set to Server.

```
@inject NavigationManager UriHelper

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (!IsAuthenticated)
        {
            UriHelper.NavigateTo("login", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, if I try to use the redirect component in the App.razor it will work, but it will display the login page inside the @Body of the main layout, therefore rendering the rest of the MainLayout as well.

The only workaround which I currently found is by using an AuthorizeView inside the MainLayout and having @Body inside a <NonAuthorized> tag as well, which I fell its weird. If I don't add the @Body it will not display anything.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @Body
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <NavMenu />
            <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div id="content">
                    <TopBar />
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
                            <ChildContent>
                                @Body
                            </ChildContent>
                            <ErrorContent Context="Exception">
                                <h3>@Exception.GetType()</h3>
                                <h3>@Exception.Message</h3>
                                <button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="()=>errorBoundary.Recover()">Clear</button>
                            </ErrorContent>
                        </ErrorBoundary>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your 2nd method, a redirect component in App.razor:

You can apply a specific layout to your login page, using the @layout attribute, which will override the default MainLayout.

In your case, where you want to reset the layout completely, we would ideally like to be able to add a line `@layout null` at the top of the file, in a similar manner to what we can do in razor pages (cshtml files).
But this option is not yet available (there's an [open request](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8340) for such a feature).

In the meantime you can use a workaround described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59532812/1531760:

Create a layout component named EmptyLayout.razor.
Add 2 lines:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@Body
```

Then, assuming you have a login.razor component that starts with the line

```
@page "/login"
```

add the following line after it:

```
@layout EmptyLayout
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try it out and see how it goes!